# folder is git ignored but Android Studio still wants commit it

Tags: git, android-studio, version-control

Folder is git ignored but Android Studio still wants commit it

I don't want to commit folder named **dep_libs**

root **.gitignore**:

```
*.iml
.gradle
/local.properties
/.idea/workspace.xml
/.idea/libraries
.DS_Store
/build
/captures
.externalNativeBuild
/library/src/main/dep_libs/
```

But it always wants commit when I press "Commit Changes" button (green one)

[image]

Quite annoying that I always have to uncheck this folder to commit only needed files/folders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just in case if you already committed it earlier and want to ignore it now you have to execute this command
`git rm --cached path/to/folder`

Comment: I guess it was locally precommited only on my pc, not server. To fix it I also had to add `-r` and `-f` flags: `git rm -rf --cached library/src/main/dep_libs/` p.s. I'm just new to working with git